# Postfix trigger when mail sent

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I need run script after postfix sent mail and get status of it (success, defered etc). Is [filters](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html) help me? I think it trigger only for incoming mail but i need for **outgoing**.
I think about parsing logs by message-id. But it is not good idea. Is there better way?

Comment: Can you give us the big picture? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @InternetSeriousBusiness I send mail through php by using _mail_ function. It put message to postfix queue. So i want to know when postfix proccess my message.

Answer (score 4):

Filters aren't going to have access to delivery status, so I don't think outgoing (after-queue content) filters will help.  You could add return-receipt in the header, but it would be easier to turn on Delivery Status Notification in postfix.  That still just gets the status back to the originating user, and I suspect you meant something system-wide.

Taking DSN a step further, you could hack postfix's bounce templates to contain a "To:" or "Bcc:" header (if the user requested status too?), sending status messages to a specific central mailbox. That may take a change to bounce itself, to allow those headers.

Personally, I'd go with parsing the logs, but you don't explain why that's bad or what specifically you want to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

you can check if any mail is deferred by issuing postfix utility `postqueue -p`